# Constructing BitSets in Scala from a predicate?

Tags: scala, bitset

Suppose I want to construct a BitSet containing all integers from 0 until n satisfying some predicate `f: Int => Boolean`.

I could write something like

```
BitSet((0 until n):_*).filter(f)
```

which of course works. But it feels rather inefficient! I'm planning on doing this inside a pretty tight loop, and would like suggestions for more efficient ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance is truly your major concern, the best option is probably to use a `mutable.BitSet` and a while loop, and then call `toImmutable` on the result.

```
val bitSet = {
  val tmp = new scala.collection.mutable.BitSet(n)
  var i = 0;
  while (i < n) {
    if (f(i)) {
      tmp += i
    }
    i = i + 1
  }
  tmp.toImmutable
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the best I could come up with at the moment

```
BitSet((0 until n).view.filter(f):_*)
```

The view part makes the `filter` method lazy. This makes sure that when the `BitSet` is created from the given sequence, it will filter on the fly. Your original suggestion creates a new `BitSet` after the first one is created.

Comment: It is not true what you say, `filter` creates an intermediate collection, even with the `view`. In fact `view` is completely useless here. `: _*` means pass the argument directly instead of wrapping it in a sequence.

Comment: Repeated params are not passed "directly" (as in pushed onto the argument stack) but rather are placed in a kind of `IndexedSeq` and that is passed to the method as a single argument. In other words, they most certainly _are_ wrapped.

Comment: @Randall Schulz: true, but schaef is right nonetheless. `Range` inherits its `filter` implementation from `TraversableLike`, defined here: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L261. As you can see it iterates over every element of the original collection (it is a mere `foreach`), so even when making the collection lazy via `view`, `filter` will force the evaluation of each element of the original collection anyway. So in this case using `view` can actually make matters worse by introducing a needless additional indirection.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most efficient "functional" way is to use `foldLeft`:

```
(1 to 5).foldLeft(BitSet())((s,i) => if (f(i)) s + i else s)
```

It doesn't create an intermediate collection but construct the collection from scratch while filtering.

The first thing I thought is to use `breakOut`, but it doesn't work for `filter`:

```
scala> val set: BitSet = (0 until 10).filter(f)(collection.breakOut)
<console>:11: error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : [From, T, To]scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[From,T,To]
 required: Int
       val set: BitSet = (0 until 10).filter(f)(collection.breakOut)
                                                           ^

scala> val set: BitSet = (0 until 10).map(_+1)(collection.breakOut)
set: scala.collection.immutable.BitSet = BitSet(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

`breakOut` doesn't create an intermediate collection too, but because `filter` doesn't have a second parameter list it can't work.